# Aligning two three items on same line

Tags: css

How can I make three items on same line with css? I want to make them on same line one after another?
This is what I have for html

```
<div class="btn-votes">
       <input type="button" title="Up" class="up"/>
            <div class="label-votes">2</div>
       <input type="button" title="Down" class="down" />  
</div>
```

And this is the css

```
.btn-votes input[type="button"]{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer; 
    margin-bottom: -20px; 
    display:inline-block;
}
.up {background-image:url("")}
.up:disabled {background-image:url('')}
.down {background-image:url("")}
.down:disabled {background-image:url('')}
.label-votes {font-size:1.0em;color:#40CD22;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;}
```

And here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzqqcv4g/1/).. Note: Images are not shown there because I have my own.. just tried to provide some image for the demo.

Comment: Your two buttons are `display:inline-block`, but your div with class `.label-votes` is not, http://jsfiddle.net/hzqqcv4g/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to your `.label-votes` class

```
.label-votes {
    font-size:1.0em;color:#40CD22;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzqqcv4g/3/

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about `.label_votes` since is inside in `btn-votes`. Thank's

Comment: One more think. How to remove this grey shadow of the buttons?

Comment: Original images that I use are transperant .png but there is this grey shadow behind them.

Comment: @Stan add `background:none;` to your `.btn-votes input[type="button"]` selector

Comment: Yeah, I tried this already but with this images are disappeared also :)

Comment: @Stan yes it kills the images, so you need to be more specific with your selectors. So use `.btn-votes input[type="button"].up` instead of `.up`. etc

Comment: My mistake. I've made it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Stan they're showing, but they're too big to fit in the box. You need to add `background-size:contain;` to your `.btn-votes input[type="button"]`. http://jsfiddle.net/hzqqcv4g/7/

Answer (score 0):

Add display:inline to all of them.

```
.up{

    width:32px;
        height:32px;
    display:inline !important;
}

.down{
      width:32px;
        height:32px;
    display:inline !important;
}

.label-votes{
    display:inline !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzqqcv4g/1/